# Как изменить url с помощью htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Мне нужно изменить url с `category.php?id=cookie` на `category/cookie`.
Я пробовал сделать так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ category.php?id=$1 [L]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но почему-то все подключенные скрипты выдают ошибку `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Comment: А почему `$2`? Первое захваченное это `$1`.

Comment: потому что вы же не любите, наверное, писать пути к скриптам от корня `src="/js/script.js"` а любите относительные пути `js/script.js`